# Emails not being sent using google calendar API (python) despite sendUpdates = 'all'

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I'm developing an app which utilises the google calendar API.

I have the event request as such:

```
event = service.events().insert(calendarId = calendar_id, sendUpdates = 'all', body=event).execute()
```

No emails are being sent when adding an event. Does `sendUpdates` need to be specified in the request body instead? Also, I currently have the app in testing not production - would this prevent emails from being sent?

Happy to post further info - can also see that this is possibly a bug?

Have attempted `sendUpdates` in various locations and the deprecated `sendNotifications` - neither has sent an email successfully.